# Is there any wordpress Plugin from WOOCOMMERCE that allow user to "select multiple products" From "PRODUCT BUNDLE"?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal-subscriptions, subscriptions

I want to give feature to user `Selection of Multiple Products` from Product Bundle on Subscriptions section.

So my question is: How would I do it? Is there any Wordpress Plugin from **WooCommerce** that provide `Selection of Multiple Product` From **Product Bundle**?

Like this link:
[Selecting particular product from list of Products for subscription and total prices calculated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmQDy.jpg)

I want this feature in Wordpress. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Woo-commerce plugin comes with a pre-built functionality of add-to-cart, User will add multiple products to the cart that he wants to purchase, then checkout the cart with total amount of all products, You don't need anything new for product bundle extension.

Please refer to the documentation of woo-commerce https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/catalog-visibility-options/ for more details.

Comment: i want to create a subscription page where.. customer can subscribe to SELECTED products from the mention ... and after selecting the products ... total amount need to be displayed with following subscriptions days... plz see this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmQDy.jpg

Comment: Sir i found my answer!! "WooCommerce Custom Product Boxes" https://wisdmlabs.com/assorted-bundles-woocommerce-custom-product-boxes-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solutions WooCommerce Product Bundle and Composite Products: Multiple Selections, activating these two plugin have solved my problem. From this link [Composite Products: Multiple Selections - WooCommerce Docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/composite-products/composite-products-multiple-selections/)